# How do I resolve "Cannot call method 'stream' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, express, vagrant

I'm trying to use ntwitter to display some tweets on putty terminal. Having installed the node modules (express and ntwitter) in the root directory, I get this error when I try running tweet_counter.js from the root directory.

```
vagrant@precise32:~/app/Twitter$ node tweet_counter

/home/vagrant/app/Twitter/tweet_counter.js:7
twitter.stream(
    ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'stream' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/app/Twitter/tweet_counter.js:7:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

//tweet_counter.js code

```
var ntwitter = require("ntwitter"),
credentials = require("./credentials.json"),
twitter;

// set up our twitter object
twitter = ntwitter(credentials);

// set up our twitter stream with three parameters,
// separated by commas
twitter.stream(
// the first parameter is a string
"statuses/filter",

// second parameter, an object containing an array
{ "track": ["awesome", "cool", "rad", "gnarly", "groovy"] },

// the third parameter is our callback for when the stream is created
    function(stream) {
        stream.on("data", function(tweet) {
             console.log(tweet.text);
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `twitter = ntwitter(credentials);` be `twitter = new twitter(credentials);` instead?

Comment: Doesn't work, still spits the same error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, i was able to fetch stream from your same program, can you please make sure you have installed correctly ntwitter, make sure you installed from your project root directory, no need to make it global, if required just save as dependency in package.json..

## you can see my output on cmd:

```
RT @ToughAmanda: Watch @WWEToughEnough tonight at 8 pm est � Don't forget                to download the app for some cool behind the scenes stuff &amp; votin…
#ReCap -&gt; #ReReplay #Exciting #Awesome
RT @DiegoNoJuuzou: #MTVHottest Demi Lovato  https://t.co/4tmtAOiV2p
41 awesome things to do in London this week http://t.co/OxM1QfxTCm
@cieraira aku dh lama xminum cool blog. Sbb xde hg mungkin. Haha
```

@CampAmerica69 sounds like such a cool camp never been to a summer camp        before haha :)
    RT @YankydoodlDandy: Villians i've come to love are Dr. Doom, Red Skull,    Joker (obviously), Kang (such an awesome villian), and the Riddler…
    Awesome! https://t.co/EDrQjEiO7I
    RT @obviouslyitsjoy: rad:
    The definition of rad is slang for an excellent person or thing.
    GO WATCH @BethanyMota's new video!!! It's awesome!!!! I loved these!! It was       such a cute idea!!! Ily Beth!!! :) http://t.co/MNkKxTIh28
    Jaguar Land Rover projects driving data directly on the windshield       http://t.co/8cX7pdQtRu via @engadget #awesome #ilovescience #cars
    RT @bea_ker: "Don - that's a cool name"

## [sweating nervously] yeah thanks haha